# Binding to a DataGrid column-wise?

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, bind

I have a datagrid with two columns and need to bind data *column-wise* i.e,

> (0,0) (0,1)
>   (1,0) (1,1)
>   .....
>   (n,0) (n,1)

I am following MVVM pattern in my application. In each sell i am going to display same set of controls whose values are bound. Is it possible to get this??

How to achieve this using MVVM???

Comment: When you say columnwise, do you mean that there will be an infinite amount of columns possible? By your description I'm not understanding if you are asking that or if you are asking how to bind each customized cell to your VM or both? What does your view model look like?

Comment: @sri What type of object is your DataGrid binding to? A simple `ObservableCollection<T>`, or `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem any different than a normal binding.  If I were doing this, I'd have an OC of types that hold each row of data

```
public ObservableCollection<Row> Rows {get;set;}
```

that I'd fill will Row instances (leaving out all INPC wiring)

```
public sealed class Row
{
  public object ColumnOne {get;set;}
  public object ColumnTwo {get;set;}
}
```

and I'd just bind that collection to the ItemsSource

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
```

Comment: Hey Will, IF i go for normal binding, from my observable collection i would be binding 0th index to my datagrid 0th row and so on. What i want is binding 0th index to first column in first row and then 1st index tosecond column in first row.. then 2nd index from observable collection to first column in my second row and 3rd index to second column in same row. I can say the binding has to go cell by cell from one column to another. And i have only two columns. Sorry i could not attach a screenshot as the website not lettting me to do !!!!

Comment: @sri: You should be able to add an image; please read [this question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) for more info.  Sounds like you might be talking about a "pivot table" type of binding, where the rows become columns and the columns become rows, but I'm not quite sure.  If that is the case, I don't think a DataGrid will let you accomplish this.  You might have to preprocess your "pivot".  There are a number of different ways you can accomplish a pivot, none of them easy.